# Calculating total price from List RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a Nested List where the list of items each has a priceReguler and a priceAfterDiscount.

How to calculate total price reguler (if priceAfterDiscount == 0)? **so the result will be like this 363000 + 158000 = 521000**.

or How to calculate total price (if priceAfterDiscount != 0)? **so the result will be like this 363000 + 119000 = 482000**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterHeaderCart.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ProductCountry productCountry = productCountryList.get(position);
    List<Product> productList = productCountry.getProductList();

    Log.e("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: " + productList.toString());
}
```

---

```
E/TAG: onBindViewHolder: [{totalAllProduct=0, finalPrice=0, totalPrice=0, image='https://google.com/171212847/file.jpg', images=null, kindId=0, kind=null, description='null', weight=0, source=Source{image = 'null',name = 'Shopciety',link = 'null',id = '0',slug = 'shopciety'}, usdPriceRegular=0.0, sourceLink='null', colors=null, priceRegular=363000, sizes=null, usdPriceAfterDiscount=0, name='4D CITYSCAPE Puzzle - Game of Thrones Winterfell 3D Puzzle', attributes=null, id=141922, sourceId=0, priceAfterDiscount=0, slug='null', isFeatured=false, country='USA'}]
E/TAG: onBindViewHolder: [{totalAllProduct=0, finalPrice=0, totalPrice=0, image='https://google.com/system/media_libraries/268171710/file.jpg', images=null, kindId=0, kind=null, description='null', weight=0, source=Source{image = 'null',name = 'Shopciety',link = 'null',id = '0',slug = 'shopciety'}, usdPriceRegular=0.0, sourceLink='null', colors=null, priceRegular=158000, sizes=null, usdPriceAfterDiscount=0, name='BIOGLAN Supplement - Gummies Probiotic 50 Chocolate Balls', attributes=null, id=142095, sourceId=0, priceAfterDiscount=119000, slug='null', isFeatured=false, country='Australia'}]
```

Comment: You definitively don't want to do that in you adapter. If your list is very long it's gonna be recalculated every time the user scrolls. Doing a lot of calculation in an adapter can lead to slow UI and lags. You should take you original list and map it to a list the adapter can process (before passing it to the adapter). This list will contain only what the adapter needs, including the calculated price.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterHeaderCart.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ProductCountry productCountry = productCountryList.get(position);
    List<Product> productList = productCountry.getProductList();

    Log.e("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: " + productList.toString());

    int sumPriceReguler = 0;
    int finalPosition = 0;
    if (productList.size() > 2) { //for get beforeItem
        for(int i = 0 ; i < productList.size() ; i ++) {
            Product product = productList.get(finalPosition);
            int beforeProductPrice = productList.get(position-1).getPriceReguler();
            if (product.getPriceAfterDiscount == 0) {
                sumPriceReguler = beforeProductPrice + product.getPriceReguler();
            } else {
                sumPriceReguler = beforeProductPrice + product.getPriceAfterDiscount()
            }
            finalPosition++;
        }
    }
    // use sumPriceReguler as you want
}
```

Comment: I get an error like this "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1" in Product product = productList.get(position);

Comment: oh sorry, i confused your list is not productList. I will edit